# android ormlite NoClassDefFoundError on Samsung S4 API 21

Tags: android, ormlite

The android project runs without problem on Samsung S7 API 24, Nexus 6 API 24, API 23 Emulator, Pixel API 23 and Galaxy Note 23 API emulators.

When I run it on devices or emulators with API 22 or 21, the following exception is thrown the first time App is launched.

```
05-04 11:48:25.045 10463-10463/com.xyz.abc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.xyz.abc, PID: 10463
                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper
                       at com.xyz.abc.database.daos.UserRecordDao.<init>(UserRecordDao.java:32)
                       at com.xyz.abc.AbcApplication.onCreate(AbcApplication.java:148)
                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Below is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
}
}

dependencies {

// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
// Optional -- Mockito framework
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/aws/aws-android-sdk-cognito-2.1.10.jar')
compile files('libs/aws/aws-android-sdk-core-2.1.10.jar')
compile files('libs/aws/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.1.10.jar')
compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+') {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.7.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.ppamorim:dragger:1.2'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.1'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.frank-zhu:pullzoomview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.techery:properratingbar:0.0.5'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Log out put from running it on API 22

```
05-08 21:18:33.431 4597-4597/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
05-08 21:18:33.431 4597-4597/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
05-08 21:18:33.432 4597-4597/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-08 21:18:33.471 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-08 21:18:34.038 4597-4625/com.xyz.abc W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
05-08 21:18:34.051 4597-4625/com.xyz.abc W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
05-08 21:18:34.062 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10007
05-08 21:18:34.063 4597-4625/com.xyz.abc W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-08 21:18:34.065 4597-4625/com.xyz.abc W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-08 21:18:34.096 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
05-08 21:18:34.096 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
05-08 21:18:34.109 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
05-08 21:18:34.113 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:4
05-08 21:18:34.113 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 4
05-08 21:18:34.125 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader p[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000003/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk"],

nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
05-08 21:18:34.138 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
05-08 21:18:34.138 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
05-08 21:18:34.144 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
05-08 21:18:34.182 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
05-08 21:18:34.182 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
05-08 21:18:34.182 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
05-08 21:18:34.182 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 1038524578
05-08 21:18:34.196 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                  adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.xyz.abc
05-08 21:18:34.235 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks@3824b269
05-08 21:18:34.235 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
05-08 21:18:34.236 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-08 21:18:34.240 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper>
05-08 21:18:34.240 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper>
05-08 21:18:34.240 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper>
05-08 21:18:34.240 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper>
05-08 21:18:34.249 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper>
05-08 21:18:34.249 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-08 21:18:34.250 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper
                                                                   at com.xyz.abc.database.daos.UserRecordDao.<init>(UserRecordDao.java:32)
                                                                   at com.xyz.abc.AbcApplication.onCreate(AbcApplication.java:140)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-08 21:18:34.261 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:8 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:9
05-08 21:18:34.261 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 9
05-08 21:18:34.285 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.
05-08 21:18:34.304 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
05-08 21:18:34.305 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 37ms
05-08 21:18:34.309 4597-4638/com.xyz.abc D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1494292714250, fatal=1}]
05-08 21:18:34.471 4597-4597/com.xyz.abc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.xyz.abc, PID: 4597
                                                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xyz.abc.database.helper.AbcDatabaseHelper
                                                                at com.xyz.abc.database.daos.UserRecordDao.<init>(UserRecordDao.java:32)
                                                                at com.xyz.abc.AbcApplication.onCreate(AbcApplication.java:140)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-08 21:22:57.870 4597-4597/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4597 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: ext {
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
}

Comment: Is `AbcDatabaseHelper` a class you wrote or is it from a third-party library?

Comment: I wrote it. public class AbcDatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {...}

Comment: Try to investigate the APK file: use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio. Check if there is more than 1 dex file. Inside the dex file, check if your class is actually present or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to fix this. It should be a multidex issue. When I reduce the number of dependencies, this problem no longer happens.

In the end I changed

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

as I only need maps and kept all other dependencies.

Still not sure why it behaves like this as clearly API 23 and 24 deals with Multidex in a different way from API 22 and below.

Hope this helps anyone with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to clean the project. Faced the similar issues at past, and cleaning and rebuilding the project solved my cases.

---

Secnd, If your AbcDatabaseHelper class is not public, it will be accessible to only same package/folder.

change

```
class AbcDatabaseHelper {

}
```

to

```
public class AbcDatabaseHelper {

}
```

---

And also, some libraries and methods can be missing on Samsung devices like S4 Mini, S3 Mini, S4, Note 2 etc. Some 3rd party libraries may not work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use Exception Class it catches all exceptions

Answer (score 0):

There is another fork for ormilite that works with the api 22. in this [github](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin) repo. You just add this to your gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.github.stephanenicolas.ormgap:ormgap-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'ormgap'
```

It has an [example](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin/tree/master/ormgap-example) that you should check to see the diferences. I hope it helps you!